# Node Fetch request works locally but fails when deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, fetch, extract, puppeteer

I have written a small function that requests data from a "hidden" API. It is a simple GET request and it works flawlessly when I run locally, but I receive a 403 Forbidden response when I try to deploy to Heroku. The strange thing is it worked several days ago no issue.

```
address  = https://a810-dobnow.nyc.gov/Publish/PublicPortalWrapper/WrapperService.svc/getPublicPortalPropertyDetailsGet/1%7C318%7CWEST%2088%20STREET%7C1

fetch(address, {
    headers: {
      accept:
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "cache-control": "max-age=0",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
      "sec-fetch-site": "none",
      "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
      // cookie:
      //   "_ga=GA1.2.1003098932.1594177672; _abck=C3A49F4C33DC14B4AEC19A7EBC5ACB7A~0~YAAQiUMkF2ogZFZzAQAAsvKfZwQfXDkq7euJF0D2hRXAI2V1AruFzXLsOUSc59t7XNzo9iAXH5X1hH0WZkHU2/jyyCcQZO7iOKhK5SV68dIBzVnbK87jIJGLiP5SnbL5Vc9cb+jStzQUpnjOLG59Z1YwYX8pBBNF1xCmUE9p5JJGHt2eA/1A+szh3Fsd7Pa1Y/gNqCYlaMeG9KobxAhWrxPGSI8UqfJEY24rP53Sjkk2RnVQtOm4Ndym5VctS0E078oS7rO2ErVUciCd7KIm6uTqAIZaLCThpn38Lvv7Bw==~-1~-1~-1; WT_FPC=id=f89669c2-f54a-4a08-8417-488c541da028:lv=1595295049155:ss=1595295008235; ASP.NET_SessionId=fvhtl1mq5byqybp0vn4rvkk0; _gid=GA1.2.778374792.1596222780; bm_mi=8303530FA5B983C6A2C37AD6A50F1AB0~DwWIcg/T4TLuW4ckdSijBe3wsAObA+OJOKRuvmdxP64cGhS6O67EOei1JDxamYFX6tF8BcezG1nFQK8QcvDTvBA2ZwT0CifQcO7VSg9cAcLoYATKRjs0vahwRFMGb3hpm826BjjMbcMrdU0GW0U1JQxqNbtc5kFZBM3022kwyv0VGDzY3NNW7BWZHqToNvx2z6qHKJgnDb1V0TeZ/AjuFP89BX784OrYSTkaiSZLbg6BnM3HmCXznFFf0+IaMhxU2MgqrGwoITehpPQfuzZ2HGx1hhfWZ0xa0MGKZnZhd0w=; ak_bmsc=728816F52039F5DD770B7D4B6536D20717408D2C753F0000316D245FB7EF451C~plc8JV/GDGNtsmUQ/jrI8X7yLHGcKff9dnWlC62FcsMQEB3ENDDfKz8e1f/edVvmGAOdiXJdHstFeuQG18Sg95iSqHA8xYy6vqPUNz2DcmRmIK4ZqgsMgXgQ7SLSvxOxFTfsIkV83XG87pDK8HpYh6oO1sI33FGj5ZsRe2y8o88+cY/xI1CAuqtQNZbHf3SzhfkP0tzqeLtUoHuH8nZPyIluF4LxGSI9WhTndADPDMap+F9gPOm12ubgZRwcgJPKyl; NSC_mc_qfstjtuhspvq_dppljf=ffffffff9eb452ce45525d5f4f58455e445a4a42378b; bm_sv=CFE4F539604441CC66374C6DBD92BDD0~7PQFpr8AaDw9KWD30agg7TrTgydB1GbhFszaf7zAlHQJaWLcaclQ66BxK2PBdF3XoSvzzvutMQWGxTWg+TRgOudrUF1Gu8yUwwIv0IMv7imBGm1deHPcQCoDo3JsMZud2DJsOC35QEV60c4j8CuPjQ=="
    },
    referrer: "https://a810-dobnow.nyc.gov/publish/",
    referrerPolicy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    body: null,
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors"
  })
```

Comment: They might be blocking AWS traffic, that's not unusual.

Comment: @pguardiario is there a way around that? proxy?

Comment: Yes. a proxy should get around that.